# Lambda expression creates multiple queries

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I have a strange LINQ issue of system.function. If my Lambda expression contains the datacontext twice it will generate multiple SQL-queries instead of (see second one) one SQL-query.

First

```
Dim whereFunction As Func(Of tasks, Boolean) = Function(task) New With {.condition =
                                                      (From i In myDataContext.taskInfo Where i.taskId = task.id).Any()
                                                 }.condition
Dim tasksLambda = myDataContext.tasks.Where(whereFunction)
Dim taskList = tasksLambda.ToList 
'generates for each task one select to taskinfo on SQL Server Profiler -> bad
```

Second

```
Dim tasksNoLambda = (From task In myDataContext.tasks Where (From i In myDataContext.taskInfo Where i.taskId = task.id).Any())
taskList  = tasksNoLambda .ToList 
'generates only one select to tasks with subselect to taskinfo on SQL Server Profiler -> good
```

Can you explain WHY it makes multiple queries instead of subqueries and/or what's the difference between these two Lambda-queries.

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: You're moving in and out of the `IQueryable`. Anytime a query crosses the boundary it has to make separate queries.

Comment: And how to prevent these multiple queries @Enigmativity? I really need the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `myDataContext.tasks` refers to a collection provided by the data source
- `.Where(whereFunction)` is an expression that must be evaluated in the client because `whereFunction` can't be generally converted to an SQL expression (it is constructing new anonymous objects and I believe there's no SQL conversion for that).
- `myDataContext.taskInfo` within the function refers back to the data source again.

Therefore there needs to be a lot of back-and-forth communication in the evaluation of the highest level expression, retrieving data from the data source, processing it in a function on the client, which in turn must retrieve more data from the data source.

Could you try the same thing without the anonymous object? Could you try this?

```
Dim whereFunction As Func(Of tasks, Boolean) = _
    Function(task) (From i In myDataContext.taskInfo Where i.taskId = task.id).Any())
```

Got it. Second attempt -- try this one:

```
Dim whereFunction As System.Linq.Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of tasks, Boolean)) = _
    Function(task) (From i In myDataContext.taskInfo Where i.taskId = task.id).Any())
```

By representing the variable as a LINQ "Expression" I think it improves LINQ's ability to convert it to other forms such as SQL.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @BlueMonkMN but unfortunately it does not make any difference. Still having this issue.

Comment: @daniel.didusch I think I got it this time.

Comment: What do you mean exactly @BlueMonkMN? I was not able to solve this issue with your answer.

Comment: @daniel.didusch Did you see my second answer? When I used this methiod, it did change the behavior in my test. Didn't it for you?

Comment: Thank you so much @BlueMonkMN, I really appreciate it! 
I marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
Dim tasksLambda  = _
    From task In myDataContext.tasks
    Group Join i In myDataContext.taskInfo On task.id Equals i.taskId Into Group
    Where Group.Any()
    Select task
```

This would be the best you can do to make it one query.

If that doesn't work then you can pull the `tasks` and `taskInfo` records into memory and do the filtering there. As long as you don't have too many records this can often be faster anyway.

Comment: Sorry @Enigmativity, that was not my target as I needed a returning Where-function.

Comment: @daniel.didusch - if you want to return a where clause **and** make only on query then you need to return an `Expression(Of Func(Of tasks, Boolean))`, not just a `Func(Of tasks, Boolean)`.